# UIImageView flattens picture

Tags: uiimageview, xcode4.2

When I add picture to the ImageView in IB - its OK! But when I add picture in code, ImageView flattens a picture and It starts to look ugly.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    if([self.navigationItem.title isEqualToString:@"Cup"]) 
    {
        [mainImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cup2"]];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:giftImage];
}
```

Why this happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [UIImageView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image), you should call [sizeToFit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit) after adding a picture.